# M2 - Show fixed shipping in shopping cart

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, shipping, shopping-cart

How can I always show the fixed or free shipping in the shoppingcart? I need to display the shipping rate (<50) or the free shipping (>50).

There is nothing that needs to be calculated or something so there should be a way to display it.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's not too hard. Where you want to display on shopping cart page? Please take a screenshot?

Comment: In the block where you see the totals and tax.